# dropdown menu not getting the correct style

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code in my React render function:

```
<div ref="btnGroup" className="dropdown">
   <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="toggle" onClick={this.toggleDropdown}></button>
   <ul class="scrollable-menu-parent dropdown-menu">
      <div>
         <form class="droplist-panel">
            <input class="droplist-search" />
            <div class="scrollable-menu">
               <li class="dropdown-item"> </li>
               ...
               ...
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In the toggle dropdown function, I am adding the open class to the topmost div.

However, the `<ul>` is not getting the auto dropdown style when it is open, the width is way larger and the positioning is also  incorrect.

Am I doing something wrong here with the dropdown, dropdown-toggle and dropdown-menu which is causing the  `<ul>` to not get correct classes?

Edit:

```
    toggleDropdown() {
        const $el = $(this.refs.btnGroup);
        if ($el.is('.open')) {
            this.closeDropdown($el);
        }
        else {
            this.openDropdown($el);
        }
    },

    closeDropdown(ele) {
        ele.removeClass('open');
        this.clearState();
    },

    openDropdown(ele) {
        ele.addClass('open');
        if (this.props.onOpen) {
            this.props.onOpen.bind(this)();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Show us your toggleDropdown function! Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135351/toggle-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs

Comment: @StefanBob Added the code

Comment: Seems like you're using jQuery together with React - you should avoid that. If you use imperative code (jQuery) inside declarative (React) it will get messy and hard to follow.